# how to trace the trigger activity in SQL?

Tags: sql-server, triggers, profiler

In my code, I am updating a column value in a particular table. I have some 10-15 triggers associated with the table.

While doing mass update, I am getting some errors in the form of select queries with un-assigned column names.

Disabling one of the many triggers, I got to know, which trigger is giving me an issue. I want to know
--> How to trace which part/trigger is giving me an issue using Profiler!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is this a [tag:sql-server] question? Note that the [tag:sql] tag is for the standard language and most database systems differ markedly in how they implement triggers. Please add a database product tag (either SQL Server or Oracle, MySQL, etc).

Comment: Done. Thanks. Its related to SQL Server

Comment: The SP:StmtStarting and SP:StmtCompleted events will trace individual trigger statements.

Answer (score 0):

You can also (if you have adequate permissions) use debug.

1) In SSMS highlight a line that will cause the trigger to kick off (an insert statement on a table that has an insert trigger.)

2) Press the Debug Icon (its a green arrow on the icon bar.)

3) Press the F11 function key. It will step through all the resulting statements including the triggers.